# Accessing bokeh server using dask distributed via ssh tunnelling

Tags: python, bokeh, dask, dask-distributed

**Issue**
I am setting up a cluster for running image analysis (moving from MPI to Dask and Dask.distributed). I connect to the master node via tunneling and I don't know how to access bokeh server.

**Steps**
  1. Connect to my server master node via ssh tunneling:
  `ssh -L 7000:localhost:7000 simone@server.se`
  2. Start `dask-scheduler --port 7001 --bokeh 7002`
  3. `ssh` to the nodes I want to use (also tunneling on port 7000) and start `dask-worker --memory-limit=200e9`
  4. Start a `jupyter notebook --port=7000 --no-browser` and open a `chrome`session and point the browser to `localhost:7000`
  5. Start a `Client()` pointing to the scheduler address
  6. `X11 forwarding` is broken and I cannot use it from my laptop

When I look at the output from the `dask-scheduler` page i get:

```
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at: tcp://130.237.132.207:7001
distributed.scheduler - INFO -        http at:              0.0.0.0:9786
distributed.scheduler - INFO -       bokeh at:              0.0.0.0:7002
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Local Directory:    /tmp/scheduler-4we9jlcj
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://192.168.0.3:43973
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, 
tcp://192.168.0.3:43973
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Receive client connection: Client-6967349a-
872f-11e7-a595-0cc47a8ebf44
```

and the `client` seems to connect correctly to the workers:

```
Scheduler: tcp://130.237.132.207:7001
Dashboard: http://130.237.132.207:7002
Workers: 1
Cores: 56
Memory: 200.00 GB
```

**Questions**
  1) Is it correct to point the browser to `port 7000` instead of `port 7001` where the schedule is set? FYI: I cannot load anything from the browser if I use localhost:7001 or any of the IP addressed of scheduler and dashboard. 
  2) How can I get access to the bokeh graph to evaluate performance?
  3) Additional bonus: is there a way that I can start multiple workers with `dask-ssh` and passing parameters such as `--memory-limit`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are hosting your bokeh dashboard on port 7002.  You need to set up a second ssh tunnel for that port as well.  This might look like the following:

```
ssh -L 7002:localhost:7002 simone@server.se
open http://localhost:7002
```

Passing through keywords to `dask-ssh` sounds like a good idea.  I recommend [opening an issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new) and, if you have time time, perhaps a pull request :)

Comment: I was just trying to do this yesterday (pass keywords through dask-ssh). Will make a note to look into adding it and creating a PR. In the meantime is there any other "quick" alternative to bring up several workers + specify bokeh port?

Comment: Most people use some sort of job manager for this (Marathon, Kubernetes, etc..) which makes tasks like this easy.  If you're using manual methods like SSH then you might also try tools like cluster-ssh.